# Is "Delay Delivery" in Outlook 2003 a function of the client or the server?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2003

If I have my Outlook 2003 client is closed when the email is intended to be sent, will the email still be sent?

Is it a function of the Exchange Server or my Outlook 2003 client?

Comment: What about if I leave it open in my session on a Termserver?

Comment: If Outlook is closed then the delayed email is never sent.  It would only be sent once Outlook was started.  You can confirm this yourself by delaying an email 5 minutes and checking when the server recieved it.

Comment: @leeand00 - Sorry, I deleted my comment by mistake but it said "You can try this yourself by attaching a large document to your file, click send and then close Outlook. Return in 1 hours time, the file will remain in the outbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends if you are running your Outlook client in cached Exchange mode or not.

**Cached Exchange mode:** Outlook ***must be open*** for the delayed send to occur at the designated time.

**Online mode:** Outlook ***can be closed*** (and the PC even shut down) and delayed send will still work- it is stored and sent by the Exchange server.

> *"This is expected. The problem is that (in cached mode) if the message were
>   to be pushed to the Exchange server you would no longer be able to re-edit
>   it or stop it from being sent without restarting Outlook in online mode.
>   Since many people set up a rule to delay sending all messages by a few
>   minutes (to prevent that "Oh dang! I didn't mean to send that yet!"
>   mistake), we decided that the behavior you're experiencing was the preferred
>   one. If you leave Outlook running, though, it will send the message at the
>   proper time".*
>
> --  Jeff Stephenson ([Outlook Development](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/delayed-send-outlook-cached-mode-t841126.html))